# Is Tai Chi effective to treat tendinitis?

Tags: medical-science, sport, yoga

I have heard and read from various (low quality) sources that [Tai Chi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%27ai_chi_ch%27uan) is effective to treat [tendinitis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tendinitis) (a.k.a. tendonitis). E.g.:

[Askville](http://askville.amazon.com/cure-tendonitis/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=369267):

> Gentle exercises such as Tai Chi, Yoga, and stretching, swimming and
>   light weight lifting are all may help cure tendonitis.

[Personal experience](http://www.andydent.com/TaiChiAndRSI.html):

> About three years ago I was caught up in such a project and developed
>   a problem with RSI (Repetitive Strain Injury, or Tendonitis) in my
>   right arm. I have tried this experiment twice and am now satisfied
>   that my daily Tai Chi is extremely important in keeping RSI at bay.

Is there any study on Tai Chi's effectiveness to treat tendinitis?

Comment: RSI is not tendinitis.  RSI is a centrally mediated pain disorder.  What sort of tendinitis are you asking about?  The tendinitis associated with inflammatory arthritis, or the age related non-inflammatory degenerative tendinitis, or that related to sports injuries?

Comment: The term RSI is indeed vague: http://www.cmu.edu/rsi/WhatIsRSI.htm ; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury . I see tendinitis is often mentioned as one form of RSI. I am interested in tendinitis related to sports injuries.

Answer (score 2):

There are no specific studies on tendinitis.

But tendinitis is an inflammatory condition and:

> TCC (tai chi chih) can be considered a useful behavioral intervention to reduce circulating levels of IL-6 in older adults who show elevated levels of this inflammatory marker and are at risk for inflammation-related morbidity [1].

Tai chi has improved symptoms in other inflammatory conditions (and non-inflammatory).

Knee osteoarthritis:

> Overall, Tai Chi appears to reduce pain and improve physical function for people with knee OA. The measures of benefit include patient-reported outcomes as well as physician assessments and several physical function tests [2].

Rheumatoid arthritis (RA):

> Tai Chi appears safe and may be beneficial for functional class I or II RA. These promising results warrant further investigation into the potential complementary role of Tai Chi for treatment of RA [3].

Fibromyalgia:

> Tai chi may be a useful treatment for fibromyalgia and merits long-term study in larger study populations [4].

---

References:

1. Irwin MR, Olmstead R. [Mitigating cellular inflammation in older adults: a randomized controlled trial of Tai Chi Chih.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21934474) Am J Geriatr Psychiatry. 2012 Sep;20(9):764-72. doi: [10.1097/JGP.0b013e3182330fd3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1097/JGP.0b013e3182330fd3). PubMed PMID: 21934474.
2. Wang C, Schmid CH, Hibberd PL, Kalish R, Roubenoff R, Rones R, McAlindon T. [Tai Chi is effective in treating knee osteoarthritis: a randomized controlled trial.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19877092) Arthritis Rheum. 2009 Nov 15;61(11):1545-53. doi: [10.1002/art.24832](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/art.24832). PubMed PMID: 19877092.
3. Wang C. [Tai Chi improves pain and functional status in adults with rheumatoid arthritis: results of a pilot single-blinded randomized controlled trial.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18487901) Med Sport Sci. 2008;52:218-29. doi: [10.1159/000134302](http://dx.doi.org/10.1159/000134302). PubMed PMID: 18487901.
4. Chenchen Wang, M.D., M.P.H., Christopher H. Schmid, Ph.D., Ramel Rones, B.S., Robert Kalish, M.D., Janeth Yinh, M.D., Don L. Goldenberg, M.D., Yoojin Lee, M.S., and Timothy McAlindon, M.D., M.P.H. *[A Randomized Trial of Tai Chi for Fibromyalgia.](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa0912611)* N Engl J Med 2010; 363:743-754August 19, 2010DOI: 10.1056/NEJMoa0912611

Comment: Your fourth reference has been criticized: http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/tai-chi-and-fibromyalgia-in-the-new-england-journal-of-medicine/

Comment: What is Tai Chi in your context? Tai Chi is a martial art, in good schools usually mixed with running, heavy lifting and fight training. If you are speaking about about training the "forms", that's about 5% of Tai Chi. I would be amazed to see "tendinitis" improved by running or fight training.

Comment: @Sulthan Two of them say that they're "classic Yang style" (forms, presumably), and one said that it's [Tai chi chih](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tai_chi_chih).